# VeraCrypt dismounting in console requires root password

Tags: sudo, veracrypt

I use VeraCrypt this way:

1. Open the VeraCrypt GUI.
2. Mount a container.
3. Enter root password for mounting.

But I need an option for "emergency" dismounting all devices. I know there is "hotkeys" in Win version but I use it on Linux, Ubuntu 16.04. So I tried to run this command in console:

`veracrypt -f -d`

But it asks for root password to do this, despite it doesn't ask for the root password in GUI when "dismount all" has been clicked.

How can I make a system-wide hotkey dismounting all devices and not asking for the password? Is it possible to "whitelist" only this command `veracrypt -f -d` in sudoers without opening a backdoor according to [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/178610/is-it-secure-to-mount-veracrypt-without-sudo-password-in-this-way)?

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your script to the `/etc/sudoers` by using the `visudo`.

See [sudo-Konfiguration (DE)](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/sudo/Konfiguration/)

```
 # group users allow to run script without password
 %users     ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/IRGENDEINSKRIPT


# to use:
sudo /usr/sbin/IRGENDEINSKRIPT
```

Comment: In your link there is the answer ;-)      
You should not use /usr/bin/veracrypt but can allow your script only allowing the umount.